# Programmatically composing a ~H sigil in LiveView

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, liveview

how can I populate a part of or a whole ~H sigil with a variable? I’m trying to use it to insert some existing html table markup into a Liveview page. I tried the following methods, but they result in texts like “#{html_codes}” or “ … ” on the page instead of inserting a table on the Liveview page.  If there is a better way to insert arbitrary html codes in  a LiveView page, I’m all ears.

```
html_codes = """
  <table> .... </table>
"""

~H"""
   #{html_codes} or <%= html_codes %>
"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Received the following tip from the Elixir Slack channel and it worked.

```
~H"""
<% = Phoenix.HTML.raw(html_codes) %>
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three things:

1. Make sure the variable you're trying to include itself uses `~H` syntax

   ```elixir
   html_codes = ~H"""
     <table> .... </table>
   """
   ```
2. Make sure the value is in the `assigns` variable

   ```elixir
   assigns = assign(assigns, html_codes: html_codes)
   ```
3. In the template, refer to the value using `@assign_name` syntax

   ```elixir
   ~H"""
     <div><p>Here's a table:</p><%= @html_codes %></div>
   """
   ```

This same syntax should work whether you're in the `render/1` callback, a function component, or a separate `*.heex` file.

Comment: Thanks, but """<table> ... </table>"""" will be brought in from a database, so how do I attach ~H to it?

Comment: You could directly call [`Phoenix.LiveView.Helpers.sigil_H/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.Helpers.html#sigil_H/2), but that would also process any EEx markup inside the untrusted content.  I'm not immediately aware of a good way to turn untrusted content into injectable structured HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your response. FYI. I added the solution provided on Elixir Slack below.